# Raspberry Pi No module named Plotly

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, plotly, plotly-python, raspberry-pi4

I have installed `plotly` on the `Raspberry Pi`. The objective is connecting to a remote MySql database and plot interactive time-series plots (that would update as the new data arrives into the MySql database). But I am running into `no module found` even after installing it. Looks like the `pip install plotly` is installing the package for python 2.7 (below screenshot) but I am using 3.3 (latest). How do I install the package for latest Python version.

Screenshot shows, installation of the module and then importing this module into the Python script:
[image]

Comment: Use “python -m pip ….” Where python points to the python you want to use.

Comment: @jkr My apologies. I just typed `python` on the terminal. Looks like it has 2.7 by default. Now I am installing 3.9.9 version, will delete the 2.7 version. Then the problem will be solved. I hope.

Comment: @jkr I did this `python3 -m pip install plotly` and it worked. Module imported without errors. Ignore my previous comment. Raspberry Pi has 3.7 python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple python versions on your machine, and the `pip` command seems to be pointing to python version 2.7. You can point pip to your desired python installation with the following command:

```
python3 -m pip install plotly
```

This will use the `pip` that is associated with `python3`.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly to your question. But since you are dealing with time-series data, you may consider Time Series DB instead of MySQL, and visualize the data with Grafana.